# Changing FAB behavior on fragments swaps

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I currently have a FAB (floating action button) on my `MainActivity`, I also have 2 fragments. I want the FAB to behave differently according to which fragment is on right now.
The way I see it there are 2 possible solutions:
1. implementing a FAB on each of the fragments.
2. implementing one FAB on the `MainActivity`, and changing his behavior according to the fragment who's on.
Is option 2 even possible, is it recommended or its just complicating things? If it's indeed possible, how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: I would take the 1st solution cuz it's easier to implement. The problem with the 2nd solution is that you cannot access the Fab-instance in the `MainActivity` from your `WhateverFragment`.

Comment: You had the ideas, show us how you kick started the ideas.

Comment: i had the same problem once i implemented a viewpager with fragments for each day. But the fab should be fix on the bottom. So i did number 2. The problem was to get access to the current fragment. I solved it by overwriting onResume(). Some people say one should avoid that but analysed the lifecycle and no problems emerge if you start with super.onResume().

Comment: What do you mean by overridding onResume(), @XxGoliathusxX? Can you please provide an example? I am stuck with the same issue now.